# Connection timeout with Jsch library

Tags: java, jsch

I have implemented the sftp connectivity using JSch library but I keep getting the connection timeout error. I have tried with increasing the timeout value but nothing seems to be working. I can however access the ftp site using brower just fine. My code is as follows:

```
public class FileTransfer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String hostName = "filetransfer.company.com";
        final int port = 22;
        final String userName = "user_name";
        final String password = "password" ;
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        String knowHosts = new StringBuilder().append(System.getProperty("user.home")).append("/.ssh/known_hosts").toString();
        System.out.println(knowHosts);
        try {
            jsch.setKnownHosts(knowHosts);
            Session session = jsch.getSession(userName, hostName, port);
            System.out.println("session created");
            session.setPassword(password);
            System.out.println("all properties set "+session.toString());
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            //session.setSocketFactory(new SocketFactoryWithTimeout());
            session.connect(60000);
            System.out.println("session connected");
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            System.out.println("channel created and connected");
            ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.get("sample_file.csv", "src/main/resources/downloaded_file.csv");
            channelSftp.exit();
            System.out.println("file download and saved in resource directory");
        } catch (JSchException | SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the error I am getting is :

```
session created
all properties set com.jcraft.jsch.Session@30f39991
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:394)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
    at com.wf.se.ftp.FileTransfer.main(FileTransfer.java:22)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Util$1.run(Util.java:362)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

any suggestion would be helpful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved this. If you did I would be curious to know what worked for you. Otherwise  I would try two things:

1. Use session.setServerAliveInterval(myKeepAliveTimeoutMsgInMilis), also in the documentation.
2. Using the channel.connect(0) with the 0 parameter this way the default connection timeout of 50 second will be applied. If using it without a parameter then there is no timeout applied. Check the [documentation](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html#connect-int-).